# Variables are not returning values when called from crontab

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron

When I call my script from crontab the variables are not returning any values. Whereas when I execute it manually (command line) it works fine.
I also observed only the $start_time and $end_time are not returning values whereas the $auto_job_name returns "mytext".
Could you please help on this?

Contents of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

auto_job_name="mytext"

start_time=`grep $auto_job_name job_status.txt`
end_time=`grep $auto_job_name job_status.txt`

echo $auto_job_name
echo $start_time
echo $end_time
```

Comment: Try setting the absolute path of your file job_status.txt

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You might write the absolute path to your job_status.txt file, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

auto_job_name="mytext"

start_time=`grep $auto_job_name /path/to/job_status.txt`
end_time=`grep $auto_job_name /path/to/job_status.txt`

echo $auto_job_name
echo $start_time
echo $end_time
```